# Update user meta field after WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I use WooCommerce with WordPress and I would like to update a custom field for the purchase of a single product at the time of payment validation with the display of the thank you page.

I started from this code but it does not work for the moment.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'checkout_update_user_meta' );
 
function checkout_update_user_meta( $order_id ) {
   $order = new WC_Order( '$order_id' );
   $user_id = $order->get_user_id();
   $items = $order->get_items();

foreach ( $items as $item ) {

$product_id = $item['product_id'];

if ( $product_id == '777' ) {    
      update_user_meta( $user_id, 'masterclass-1', 'ok' );
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'checkout_update_user_meta' );
 
function checkout_update_user_meta( $order_id ) {
   $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
   $user_id = $order->get_user_id();
   $items = $order->get_items();

foreach ( $items as $item ) {

$product_id = $item['product_id'];

if ( $product_id === 777 ) {    
      update_user_meta( $user_id, 'masterclass-1', 'ok' );
  }
}
}
```

The issue with your code was that you wrapped the `$order_id` in single quotes. This line `$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );` can also be replaced as `$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );`

[image]

Comment: Thank you I tried with the updated code but it still does not come to update the meta field

Comment: Updated code just tested OK

Comment: You added the code in the thankyou.php page? And your custom field is added with ACF? I'm trying to figure out why it's not working for me.

Comment: Add the code to your active theme `functions.php`

Answer (score 0):

I just modified your code to Update user meta field after woocommerce checkout according to your need. Please check my changes and hope it will work

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'checkout_update_user_meta' );
 
function checkout_update_user_meta( $order_id ) {
   $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
   $user_id = $order->get_user_id();
   $items = $order->get_items();

foreach ( $items as $item ) {

$product_id = $item->get_product_id();

if ( $product_id == 777 ) {    
      update_user_meta( $user_id, 'masterclass-1', 'ok' );
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you I tried with the updated code but it still does not come to update the meta field